# Cumulative variable for a real-time input and output stream of objects?

Tags: json, stream, jq, accumulate

I am dealing with a real-time, never-ending stream of objects.

Is there way to have a variable keeping its value from object to object *without waiting until the end of the stream*, outputting it immediately after JQ processed the next object from input?

For example, to have average temperature for all temperature measurements so far?

Input:

```
{"temp":10}
{"temp":20}
{"temp":15}
{"temp":11}
```

with code like

```
jq -n --unbuffered '
inputs
| magic(.temp, $count, $avg) as $avg
| {temp, $avg}'
```

Output:

```
{"temp":10, "avg":10}
{"temp":20, "avg":15}
{"temp":15, "avg":15}
{"temp":11, "avg":14}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Or at least if your OS allows that sort of thing (*).

The trick is to use `foreach`, like so:

```
< stream.json jq -nc --unbuffered '
foreach inputs as $in ({};
   if .n == null then {n: 1, total: $in.temp}
   else .n += 1 | .total += $in.temp
   end;
   $in + {avg: (.total / .n )})
'
```

or more concisely:

```
< stream.json jq -nc --unbuffered '
foreach inputs as $in ({};
   .n += 1 | .total += $in.temp;
   $in + {avg: (.total / .n )})
'
```

---

(*) I've tested this using a bash shell.

Comment: Brilliant! I tried `foreach` before asking, but failed to attach current object to the running average. `$in + { . | something}` in EXTRACT does the job.

Comment: Could you help with understanding how `inputs` work here? I will need to pre-filter inputs several times in a different ways, one for each `foreach` (and I need several of `foreach`s). Strangely, `foreach inputs` works differently from `inputs | foreach`.

Comment: It's not strange, because in an expression of the form `foreach S ...`, S is understood to be a stream.  However it is true that `foreach` is a bit tricky to understand, but it is documented in the jq manual, and there are numerous other resources that you can find by googling.  One hint: it is doubtful that you will want to use `inputs` more than once in your jq program.